In html select multiple pass many values with the same key
I'm working with an application that uses web pages to launch db procedures (as post).
In html code I have:
<select name="key" multiple>
    <option value="val1">val1</option>
    <option value="val2">val2</option>
...
<option value="valn">valn</option>

When I mark few of them and click submit, following code is send:
key=val1&key=val2&key=val3...
This is caught by db procedure like func(key varchar2). Unfortunatelly procedure catch only the first value.
Is possible in plain html get only one key?
ex. key=val1val2val3
or values separated by something (, ; /)?
Or maybe there is another approach that will allow me to retrieve all the options selected by the user?
I searched a soution but I didn't find. Also tried to apply js to get a comma separated list but I'm a database base developer not web developer and I couldn't do it. Apart the fact that on target system js is blockedd.

Share your submit code

This normally involves server side coding

You need this, simpler and straight forward. Send this urlEncodedData value to server as application/x-www-form-urlencoded content type


document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = e =>{
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(e.target);
  const key = formData.getAll('key');
  formData.delete('key');
  
  let urlEncodedData = new URLSearchParams(formData).toString();
  urlEncodedData+= `&key=${key}`
  console.log(urlEncodedData); // send this to server as application/x-www-form-urlencoded type
}
<form id='form'>
  <input type='text' name='text' required/>
  <select name='key' multiple required>
          <option value="val1">val1</option>
          <option value="val2">val2</option>
          <option value="val3">val2</option>
  </select>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>



Output value text=test&key=val1,val2,val3 where key value must be separated by ,
